# How can I return the value of a column in a new column based on conditions with python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, hierarchy, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe with three columns

```
 a b c
[1,0,2] 
[0,3,2] 
[0,0,2]
```

and need to create a fourth column based on a hierarchy as follows:

If column a has value then column d = column a

if column a has no value but b has then column d = column b

if column a and b have no value but c has then column d = column c

```
 a b c d
[1,0,2,1] 
[0,3,2,3] 
[0,0,2,2]
```

I'm quite the beginner at python and have no clue where to start.

Edit: I have tried the following but they all will not return a value in column d if column a is empty or None

```
df['d'] = df['a']
df.loc[df['a'] == 0, 'd'] = df['b']
df.loc[~df['a'].astype('bool') &  ~df['b'].astype('bool'), 'd'] = df['c']
```

```
df['d'] = df['a']
df.loc[df['a'] == None, 'd'] = df['b']
df.loc[~df['a'].astype('bool') &  ~df['b'].astype('bool'), 'd'] = df['c']
```

```
df['d']=np.where(df.a!=0, df.a,\
                                          np.where(df.b!=0,\
                                                   df.b, df.c)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: please paste your data if possible, seems 'a' has space or other value

Comment: it is only NaN and int() - from 1.0 up to 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple one-liner would be,

```
df['d'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).bfill(axis=1)['a'].astype(int)
```

---

#### Step by step visualization

Convert no value to NaN

```
     a    b  c
0  1.0  NaN  2
1  NaN  3.0  2
2  NaN  NaN  2
```

Now backward fill the values along rows

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  2.0  2.0
1  3.0  3.0  2.0
2  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Now select the required column, i.e `'a'` and create a new column `'d'`

Output

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  2  1
1  0  3  2  3
2  0  0  2  2
```

Comment: Thank you, however, there are other columns in the whole df that don't need changing. I will try to create a new df, do this and merge the dataframes again

Comment: The other columns don't really change, I have depicted for illustration/understanding only. The code works as is creating new column without changing other data. @DCM_paddington

Comment: Thank you. this solved my problem. Since the columns a/b/c in the original df were in a unfortunate order (b/a/e/c/) I have created a new df, used this method and implemented column d in the original df.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (df is your dataframe)

```
df['d']=np.where(df.a!=0 and df.a is not None, df.a, np.where(df.b!=0 and df.b is not None, df.b, df.c))

>>> print(df)
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  2  1
1  0  3  2  3
2  0  0  2  2
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not return a value in column 'd' if column a is 0 or None

Comment: I have added some check for None values. If your None values are in different format (eg as text 'None' or 'Nan', etc), adjust the code or let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,2], [0,3,2], [0,0,2]], columns = ('a','b','c'))
print(df)

df['d'] = df['a']
df.loc[df['a'] == 0, 'd'] = df['b']
df.loc[~df['a'].astype('bool') &  ~df['b'].astype('bool'), 'd'] = df['c']
print(df)
```

Comment: This does also not return a value in column 'd' if column a is 0 or None